# Cassandra 2.0, CQL 3.x Update ...USING TIMESTAMP

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am planning to use the Update...USING TIMESTAMP... statement to make sure that I do not overwrite fresh data with stale data while having to avoid doing at least LOCAL_QUORUM writes.

Here is my table structure.

```
Table=DocumentStore
DocumentID (primaryKey, bigint)
Document(text)
Version(int)
```

If the service receives 2 write requests with Version=1 and Version=2, regardless of the order of arrival, the business requirement is that we end up with Version=2 in the database.

Can I use the following CQL Statement?

```
Update DocumentStore using <versionValue>
SET  Document=<documentValue>,
Version=<versionValue>
where DocumentID=<documentIDValue>;
```

Has anybody used something like this? If so was the behavior as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a known technique. Although it should be

```
UPDATE "DocumentStore" USING TIMESTAMP <versionValue>
SET  "Document" = <documentValue>,
"Version" = <versionValue>
WHERE "DocumentID" = <documentIDValue>;
```

You missed a `TIMESTAMP` keyword, and also since you are using case sensitive names, you should enclose them in quotes.